# Arithmetic expressions in Bash?

Tags: bash, floating-point, math, expression

I had used several ways to do some simple integer arithmetic in BASH (3.2). But I can't figure out the best (preferred) way to do it.

```
result=`expr 1 + 2`
result=$(( 1 + 2 ))
let "result = 1 + 2"
```

What are the fundamental differences between those expressions?
Is there other ways to do the same?

Is the use of a tool like `bc` mandatory for floating point arithmetic?

```
result=`echo "7/354" | bc`
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Bash, `let` allows multiple assignments on a line:

```
let a=3 b=4 c=5
```

As you show in your question, quoting the argument to `let` allows you to put spaces around the operators. You can, however, omit the quotes if you avoid using spaces.

Another form using double parentheses at the beginning of the statement (instead of the `i=$((j + 1))` form) allows you to include spaces around the equal sign or do post- or pre- increment or decrement and additional assignment operations:

```
(( a = ( b + c ) * 4 ))
(( count++ ))
(( d = --c**2 ))
(( e *= 2 ))
(( f = 3, g = 5 ))    # multiple operations require a comma separator
```

If you do `help "(("` it says that the double parentheses is 'Equivalent to "`let EXPRESSION`".'

You can use the `declare` builtin to make assignments, including indirectly:

```
blue=2
name=blue
declare $name=4
echo $blue    # result: 4
echo ${!name} # result: 4
```

**Edit:**

The `$(())` construct is called "[arithmetic expansion](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)" and causes the contents to be evaluated as an integer expression. It's a syntax element of the shell.

If a variable is declared as an integer you don't need to use either form of double parentheses, you can omit the dollar sign from the variable name (as in the double-parentheses forms), but you can't add spaces around operators:

```
declare -i x=1   # set integer, initialize to 1
declare +i s=1   # clear integer, initialize to 1
x+=1             # could also be x=x+1
echo $x          # result: 2 (addition)
s+=1             # could also be s=$s+1, requires a "$"
echo $s          # result: 11 (string concatenation)
```

Unlike the forms above, calling `expr` involves spawning an external executable which can be quite expensive for a lot of calculations in a loop. The *only* time it should be used is in environments where the shell can't do its own arithmetic or for portability when a script may find its way into such an environment. POSIX shells have arithmetic capability so it would be a concern only with older systems.

Regarding the use of `bc` for floating point arithmetic, it or something similar is required when using Bash and many other shells. POSIX says that "Only signed long integer arithmetic is required."

Two shells that do support float math are ksh and zsh. In addition to `bc`, you can use `dc`, AWK, Python, Perl and others from within a Bash script.

One thing that Bash *will* do with floating point numbers is print them with the `printf` builtin (note that there is also an external `printf`, but builtins have priority).

```
printf "%'14.4f\n" 1234.56  # result "    1,234.5600" (in my locale)
```

Comment: You failed to discuss the implications of spawning `expr` etc. and whether `$(())` is a bultin or not.

Comment: @Vlad: I hope you find the additions an improvement.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer your second option, since it doesn't need an external utility:

```
result=$(( 1 + 2 ))
```

The first option calls out to `expr` to do the math - I'm not familiar with `let`.  Another alternative to `bc` is `dc`.  Choose your favourite.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say it's "mandatory" but `bc` is probably your best bet for general purpose arithmetic.

For something fancier, you can always pipe through Perl.

The downside of both thee approaches is that they both open a child process, so doing it in a tight loop will be slower than native bash expressions (same problem arises with use of backticks, in your first example). I'm not sure whether `$(())` calls a child process.

Answer (score 3):

`Is the use of a tool like bc mandatory for floating point arithmetic?`

No, if you are using a shell that supports floating point, eg zsh, ksh. Otherwise, if you want to do more advanced floating point maths, use either one of these, `bc/awk/dc`. Of course, Perl/Python etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

The third option you have is a lot less readable as it does not look like an assignment operator. The first, as noted by others, calls an external command