# Floating point maths in bash using bc

Tags: bash, bc

I am trying to do some floating point maths in bash. I have been examining this thread, as well as many other sources of information: [BASH Arithmetic Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517727/bash-arithmetic-expressions)

Just as an example, I am using:

```
c='echo "2\*4.2"|bc'
echo $c
```

but getting:

```
echo "2\*4.2"|bc
```

out.

I want just the value of the multiplication.

I have also tried:

```
$c='echo "2\*4.2"|bc'
echo $c
```

But then I get:

```
"2\*4.2"|bc=echo "2\*4.2"|bc
```

I'm quite confused, any suggestions?

Ciara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c=`echo "2*4.2"|bc`
echo $c
```

**Note the difference between quote <kbd>'</kbd> and back tick <kbd>`</kbd>

or

```
c=$(echo "2*4.2"|bc)
echo $c
```

Comment: The second version is vastly preferred. You only need to know about the backticks to recognize them in old code, or if you are playing code golf.

Comment: Thanks Kent and chepner I didn't notice that at all!