# I have two variables a=2 b=2 and now i want (a + b) *2 and store this in c variable

Tags: c, unix

How To Perform addition and multiplication simultaneously in Unix ?
Eg : a + b * 2

Comment: in the shell? if so, which one? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BASH Arithmetic Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517727/bash-arithmetic-expressions)

Comment: Well which do you want? The title says `(a+b)*2` but your example says `a+b*2` which is really `a+(b*2)` based on the rules of the order in which operators will be interpreted if no parens are used (always use parens for this reason, to be clear in your intention).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $((a+b*2))
```

or

```
echo "$a+$b*2"|bc
```

Comment: this is for bash shell

Answer (score 0):

```
a=2
b=2
((c=(a+b)**2))
echo $c
16
```