# Arithmetic in Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

After executing this

```
ta=`zcat abc.log.2019071814.gz |grep "R_MT"|grep "A:1234"|grep "ID:413"|awk -F"|" '{print $20}'|sort|uniq -c|awk '{$1=$1};1'`
```

Here $20 indicates the "S:" entry in each row (I am taking the unique count of all s values),I am getting result as

```
93070 S:1 11666 S:8 230 S:9
```

so what I need is the sum of all occurrence of s values .i.e 93070+11666+230
so result be total=104966

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BASH Arithmetic Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517727/bash-arithmetic-expressions)

Comment: I want to introduce "zgrep"  ==> `zgrep "R_MT" abc.log.2019071814.gz .... UUOC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo 93070 S:1 11666 S:8 230 S:9 | sed -E 's,S:[0-9]+,,g' | sed 's,  ,+,g'  | bc -
104966
```

Answer (score 1):

Append to your last `awk`:

```
| awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

or use this (`awk` ignores columns with S:1, S:8 and S:9):

```
echo $ta | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) t+=$i; print t; t=0}'
```

or use every second column:

```
echo $ta | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2) t+=$i; print t; t=0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't help you all the way, but know that you can use `bc` to perform arithmetic.

```
echo "93070 + 11666 + 230" | bc
```

would give you:

```
104966
```

Comment: On that basis it's also worth knowing that `$(())` can be used e.g. `result=$(($x + $y))`