# How to convert result as Integer in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

when I do

```
$ ls | wc -l
703
```

It gave me the result 703, I want to print 702 `(703-1)`

How can I do it in bash?

Comment: `echo $(( $(ls | wc -l) - 1 ))`?? Or even better, `( set -- *; shift; echo $# )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arithmetic expansion:

```
result=$(( $(ls | wc - l) - 1))
```

or just ignore one of the files

```
result=$(ls | tail -n+2 | wc -l)
```

Note that it doesn't work if filenames contain the newline character; use `ls -q` to get one filename per line in such a case. This applies to the first solution, too, if you're interested in the number of files and not the number of lines in their names.

Answer (score 2):

(Cheeky answer) Remove one line from the output before counting :D

```sh
ls | sed '1d' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert result as Integer in bash

@choroba has already answered this question and it should have solved OP's problem. However, I want to add more to his answer.

The OP's wants to convert the result into Integer but `Bash` doesn't have any data type like `Integer`.

Unlike many other programming languages, Bash does not segregate its variables by "type." Essentially, Bash variables are character strings, but, depending on context, Bash permits arithmetic operations and comparisons on variables. The determining factor is whether the value of a variable contains only digits.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518274/5735010) for arithmetic operation in Bash.

See [this](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html) for a best example to learn the untyped nature of Bash. I have posted the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# int-or-string.sh

a=2334                   # Integer.
let "a += 1"
echo "a = $a "           # a = 2335
echo                     # Integer, still.


b=${a/23/BB}             # Substitute "BB" for "23".
                         # This transforms $b into a string.
echo "b = $b"            # b = BB35
declare -i b             # Declaring it an integer doesn't help.
echo "b = $b"            # b = BB35

let "b += 1"             # BB35 + 1
echo "b = $b"            # b = 1
echo                     # Bash sets the "integer value" of a string to 0.

c=BB34
echo "c = $c"            # c = BB34
d=${c/BB/23}             # Substitute "23" for "BB".
                         # This makes $d an integer.
echo "d = $d"            # d = 2334
let "d += 1"             # 2334 + 1
echo "d = $d"            # d = 2335
echo


# What about null variables?
e=''                     # ... Or e="" ... Or e=
echo "e = $e"            # e =
let "e += 1"             # Arithmetic operations allowed on a null variable?
echo "e = $e"            # e = 1
echo                     # Null variable transformed into an integer.

# What about undeclared variables?
echo "f = $f"            # f =
let "f += 1"             # Arithmetic operations allowed?
echo "f = $f"            # f = 1
echo                     # Undeclared variable transformed into an integer.
#
# However ...
let "f /= $undecl_var"   # Divide by zero?
#   let: f /= : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
# Syntax error! Variable $undecl_var is not set to zero here!
#
# But still ...
let "f /= 0"
#   let: f /= 0: division by 0 (error token is "0")
# Expected behavior.


#  Bash (usually) sets the "integer value" of null to zero
#+ when performing an arithmetic operation.
#  But, don't try this at home, folks!
#  It's undocumented and probably non-portable behavior.


# Conclusion: Variables in Bash are untyped,
#+ with all attendant consequences.

exit $?
```

Comment: Not quite. In `bash`, a string to be treated as an integer value can be prefixed with a base specifier: `echo $(( 010 ))` outputs 8, but `echo $(( 10#010 ))` outputs `10`. The key is that. A pure string will also be treated as a parameter reference. `echo $(( foo ))` outputs 0 if `foo` unset; `foo=3; echo $(( foo ))` outputs 3.